# Oracle SQL Check Error

Tags: oracle, ddl

Why will my command not work when i use the check constraint? The table can be added when the check is not included.

```
 create table Car (
      CarID           number(32,0) NOT NULL ,
      PurchaseDate  date,
      Colour  varchar2(10) NOT NULL CHECK (Colour IN ("Red", "Blue", "Green")),
      CONSTRAINT CAR_PK PRIMARY KEY (CarID),
      FOREIGN KEY (CarID) REFERENCES Vehicle(ID)

    );

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
02438. 00000 -  "Column check constraint cannot reference other columns"
*Cause:    attempted to define a column check constraint that references
           another column.
*Action:   define it as a table check constriant.
```

Comment: try Purchase Date date to PurchaseDate date

Comment: Date  isnt the problem

Comment: Use single-quotes instead of double-quotes for the status literals.

Comment: It should be `CHECK (Colour IN`,   `not  CHECK (Status IN` and single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: it was the quotes that did it. Thank you

Comment: String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes. Please read the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 create table Car (
      CarID           number(32,0) NOT NULL ,
      PurchaseDate  date,
      Colour  varchar2(10) NOT NULL CHECK (Colour IN ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green')),
      CONSTRAINT CAR_PK PRIMARY KEY (CarID),
      FOREIGN KEY (CarID) REFERENCES Vehicle(ID)

    );
```

No double quotes are allowed in oracle SQL